# Safari PHP form submission -file upload hangs

Tags: php, html, safari

I have an issue with safari 5+. When client selects the image file to upload through a simple HTML form the MAC version of Safari 5.1 (so far the only browser I found which is doing this) keeps hanging indefinitely.

I have my upload time and size in php.ini set correctly and it works in all other browsers (FF, Opera even IE!) so I do not suppose I have some rookie mistake in the HTML or PHP.

I have searched through many posts and found a bug report which is related to this issue (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5760). Also I found several Ajax workarounds but none of them has been the right fit. I am not using Ajax on this page and actually due to redirects I do not want to anyway.

**Does anyone know the solution?**

Also.... suggestions like adding `<? header('Connection: close'); ?>` to the file make things worse for Opera.

**Edit: April 10, 2013**
I still did not figure out why Safari hangs on some image uploads. I am making this edit in case someone has a similar problem. BTW when Safari is ran in the VirtualBox the upload fails every time unlike Firefox or IE which works fine. (perhaps a settings issue?)

I found this workaround which is very easy to implement and so far worked with every mainstream browser I could test. (Source: http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/ ) However the original question still stands. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for lighttpd:

```
$HTTP["useragent"] =~ "Safari" {
$HTTP["useragent"] !~ "Chrome" {
  server.max-keep-alive-requests = 0
}
}
```

Jamis Buck discovered it and I added the config lines.
The second rule avoids restricting keepalives to Chrome which also has the Safari substring.
Courtesy of https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5760