# These visibility settings work in every browser except for safari. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

These visibility settings work in every browser except for Safari. I am losing my mind trying to figure out why. The JS script is located in the html  section. I know the code gets through the "if (pass == true) {" section, because a javascript alert notice pops up when I add it. It just seems to completely ignore the visibility settings though.

Help, please! haha

update: it's starting to look like it's a problem with the way the php info is processing my form. The visibility settings take effect if I hit "stop" after hitting "submit" while it's uploading a file. Every other browser seems to update the visibility settings before engaging the file upload. Why is safari waiting for the file to finish uploading first?

EDIT: Added full javascript so you can see my file upload check

EDIT: Added my form and php check info to see how the form is receiving this script

### HTML/PHP

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        $currentband = $_POST['band'];
        $currentband = strtolower($currentband);
        $pass = true;
        $handle = fopen("submissions.oi","r");
        $line = fgets($handle); $line = fgets($handle);
        $line = trim($line);
        $oldband = strtolower($line);
        $x = 1;
        if ($oldband == $currentband) { $pass = false; }
        while ($line != '') {
          for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $line = fgets($handle);
          }
          $line = trim($line);
          $oldband = strtolower($line);
          if ($oldband == $currentband) { $pass = false; }
          $x += 1;
        }
        if ($pass == true) { echo '<div id="thumbsup"> </div>'; }
        else if ($pass == false) { echo '<div id="sadface"> </div>'; }
      }
      else { echo '<div id="upload"> </div>'; }
    ?>
      <h2 style="font-style:italic;">Submit your music</h2>
      <h3><p><font size="4">If you're ready to get involved in a fresh new approach to music distribution, we encourage you to upload one of your songs.<br>As one of our select few guests, we guarantee that your single will be broadcast during the first round of voting.<br>That's right! YOU will definitely be heard in the very first round of broadcasting, no matter what.</font></p>
      <font size="2">
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
          if ($pass == true) {
            $filename = ''.time().stripslashes($_FILES['datafile']['name']);
            if ($_POST['testing'] == '') { $testing = 'No';}
            else if ($_POST['testing'] == 'Yes') { $testing = 'Yes';}
            $file = fopen("submissions.oi","a");
            fwrite($file, $_POST['email'] . "\n" . $_POST['band'] . "\n" . $_POST['song'] . "\n" . $filename . "\n" . $testing . "\n" ."\n");
            fclose($file);
            $target_path = "submissions/";
            $target_path = $target_path . basename( $filename);
            move_uploaded_file(stripslashes($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name']), $target_path);
            if ($testing == 'Yes') { $testmsg = 'want'; }
            else if ($testing == 'No') { $testmsg = 'NOT want'; }
            $to = "submissions@ourindustry.net";
            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $band_name = stripslashes($_POST['band']);
            $song_name = stripslashes($_POST['song']);
            $subject = "A new song submission has been received!";
            $message = "\"" . $band_name . "\" has submitted their song \"" . $song_name . "\" and does " . $testmsg . " to be included in future testing." . "\n \n" . "This is submission #: " . $x . "\n" . "File name: " . $filename;
            $headers = "From: " . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $from = "alpha@ourindustry.net";
            $subject = "Thank you for submitting your song to OUR INDUSTRY";
            $message = "<p>Dear \"" . $band_name . "\",</p><p>Thank you for submitting your song \"" . $song_name . "\".<br>By doing so you have secured yourself a position in the upcoming voting round.<br>We will be in touch soon when the next alpha phase begins.<br>Please add this e-mail address to your whitelist.</p><p><a href='http://www.ourindustry.net/'>www.ourindustry.net</a></p>";
            $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);          
            echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'patience\').style.visibility=\'hidden\';</script><center><div id="thumbsup-dim" style="right: 0; left:0;"></div><br><br><table style="width: 700px; height:220px;" cellpadding="2"><tbody><tr><td><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:28px;">Your upload was successful!<br></h4><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:20px;">We will be in touch as soon<br>as the voting round begins.</h4></td></tr></tbody></table></center></font>';
          }
          else if ($pass == false) {
            echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'patience\').style.visibility=\'hidden\';</script><center><div id="sadface-dim" style="right: 0; left:0;"></div><br><br><table style="width: 700px; height:220px;" cellpadding="2"><tbody><tr><td><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:28px;">Sorry!<br></h4><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:20px;">We are currently receiving only one single per band.<br></h4><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:14px;">E-mail us to make arrangements if another band has uploaded using your band name.</h4></td></tr></tbody></table></center></font>';
          }
        }
        else {
          echo '  
        <form name="myForm" action="index.php#slide7" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="upload-form">
          <center>
            <br><br>
            <table style="width: 500px; height:220px;" cellpadding="2">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="width:100%; height: 40px;"><font size="4" style="text-decoration:underline"><center>Here\'s how to get started<br></center></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:60%">E-mail address:</td> <td><input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" class="ss-item-required" name="email" size="30" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Band Name:</td> <td><input type="text" class="ss-item-required" name="band" size="30" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Song Name:</td> <td><input type="text" class="ss-item-required" name="song" size="30" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Select a MP3 file for upload (15mb max):</td><td><input class="upload-file" data-max-size="15728640" type="file" id="fUpload" name="datafile" size="40" accept=".mp3" onchange="checkextension()" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 200px;" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Check the box to be included in future testing</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="Yes"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div><input style="visibility:visible;" type="submit" value="Send" id="i_submit" onclick="formcheck();"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </center>
        </form>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 579px; bottom: 57px">
          <div style="position: relative; left: 12px;" class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ourindustry.net" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div><br>
          <div style="position: relative; bottom: -7px">Like/Share Our Facebook Page</div>
        </div>
      </font>';}?>
      <div id="reel" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
      <div id="patience" style="visibility:hidden;"><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:20px;">... UPLOADING ...</h4><br><h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:14px;">Please be patient</h4></div>
```

### JS

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
                    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
                        var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                        var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
                        if ($target) {
                            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                            $(this).click(function() {
                                $("#nav li a").removeClass("active");
                                $(this).addClass('active');
                                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 600);
                                return false;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

      function checkextension() {
        var file = document.querySelector("#fUpload");
        if ( /\.(mp3)$/i.test(file.files[0].name) === false ) { 
          alert("Sorry, this is not an mp3 file.\nTry again."); 
          document.getElementById("fUpload").value = "";
        }
      }

      $(function(){
        var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
        var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
        $('.upload-form').submit(function(e) {
          if(fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
            if(fileSize>maxSize) {
              alert('File size is more then ' + maxSize + ' bytes.\nPlease upload a smaller mp3.');
              return false;
            }
          } 
        });
      });

      function formcheck() {
        var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
        var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
        var pass = true;
        var emailFilter = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$/;
        var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
        if (!emailFilter.test(email)) { pass = false; }
        if (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value == "") { pass = false; }
        if (document.forms["myForm"]["band"].value == "") { pass = false; }
        if (document.forms["myForm"]["song"].value == "") { pass = false; }
        if (document.forms["myForm"]["datafile"].value == "") { pass = false; }
        if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
          var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
          if(fileSize>maxSize) { pass = false; }
        }
        if (pass == true) {

          document.getElementById('i_submit').style.visibility='hidden';
          document.getElementById('reel').style.visibility='visible';
          document.getElementById('patience').style.visibility='visible';
          console.log(document.getElementById('i_submit'));
        }
      }


</script>
```

Comment: Use the display property to control visibility.

document.getElementById('i_submit').style.display='none'

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work either.

Comment: The really odd thing, is that if I add a "alert('test');" right before the visibility changes in the javascript... the alert pops up. Then, if i leave that alert popup window on the screen for about 2 seconds and click "close" the visibility settings *do* work. I am baffled.

Comment: What is your return if you do this in safari?

console.log(document.getElementById('i_submit'))

Is it null or undefined?

Comment: Where should I put this piece of code?
After the visibility setting changes?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code so that we can have a minimally working example of what you have.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll post the entire code.

I just noticed that when I hit "stop" while a file upload is taking place the visibility options do kick in. It looks like my file upload is hanging up the visibility settings in safari, yet it doesn't in any other browser. Posting the full code now.

Comment: Note that @ScottMarcus mentioned **relevant** code, not full code. Reduce your code to the minimum necessary to show the behavior you are not expecting. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Okay, got ya. I will post the rest of my javscript, as it contains the file upload info

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `input type=email` and the `required` attribute?

Comment: you can put it anywhere. I am just interested to see if Safari is actually grabbing the DOM element as that may be the issue.

Comment: Hey, i just posted the entire form.
You can see an e-mail entree is part of the form, hence the e-mail type being checked in the form check. Required is being used to make sure users enter info.

Comment: When i added the console.log(document.getElementById(i_submit)) I get:
<input style="visibility:visible;" type="submit" value="Send" id="i_submit" onclick="formcheck();">

It seems to be noticing the change

Comment: Again, I've noticed that when I hit "stop" during the upload process, the visibility settings actually kick in and work. I think the root of the problem has something to do with the php action.... yet it's not a problem in any other browser.

Comment: it's starting to look like it's a problem with the way the php info is processing my form. The visibility settings take effect if I hit "stop" after hitting "submit" while it's uploading a file. Every other browser seems to update the visibility settings before engaging the file upload. Why is safari waiting for the file to finish uploading first?

Comment: I found this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894348/safari-php-form-submission-file-upload-hangs

But I have absolutely no idea what lighttpd is or how I would set it up

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in Safari and it seems to work. Maybe simplify things until they start working?

```js
function formcheck() {
  var pass = true;
  if (pass == true) {
    document.getElementById('i_submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('patience').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input style="visibility:visible;" type="submit" value="Send" id="i_submit" onclick="formcheck();">
</div>
<div id="patience" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:20px;">
    ... UPLOADING ...
  </h4><br>
  <h4 style="font-style:italic; font-size:14px;">
    Please be patient
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that when I hit "stop" while a file upload is taking place the visibility options do kick in. It looks like my file upload is hanging up the visibility settings in safari, yet it doesn't in any other browser. Posting the full code now.

Comment: Again, I've noticed that when I hit "stop" during the upload process, the visibility settings actually kick in and work. I think the root of the problem has something to do with the php action.... yet it's not a problem in any other browser. I've posted the full javascript and php/html for the form.

Comment: it's starting to look like it's a problem with the way the php info is processing my form. The visibility settings take effect if I hit "stop" after hitting "submit" while it's uploading a file. Every other browser seems to update the visibility settings before engaging the file upload. Why is safari waiting for the file to finish uploading first?

Comment: I found this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894348/safari-php-form-submission-file-upload-hangs

But I have absolutely no idea what lighttpd is or how I would set it up